# Is there a way to associate models within itself based on parent_id, and then associate with another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

That title sounds weird, so let me try to explain what it is I'm trying to accomplish.

Let's say I have a Category model, and the structure looks a little like this:

### categories

id

name

parent_id

---

I also have a model for articles

### articles

id
category_id

---

If I have a category named "News" with id: 1, and then a subcategory for it named "World News" with the id: 2 and parent_id: 1, if I have an article with category_id: 1 and another article with category_id: 2, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
category = Category.find 2 # This is the subcategory
category.articles # => Shows just the article belonging to that category
```

And

```
category = Category.find 1 # This is the parent category
category.articles # => Shows BOTH articles, the one for the child and the one for parent
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a tree structure for your categories. Using `parent_id` is the most obvious way to implement it, but it gets complicated when you want to query children.

A better solution is to use a [nested set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model), which adds a bit of complication on insert/delete but pays off with very simple queries.

You can do the research to implement this, but as with a lot of things in rails, it's a solved problem. Use [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/) which will take care of all of this for you.

Once you have installed the gem, create this migration:

```
def up
  add_column :categories, :lft, :integer
  add_column :categories, :rgt, :integer

  Category.reset_column_information!
  Category.rebuild!
end

def down
  remove_column :categories, :lft
  remove_column :categories, :rgt
end
```

Then add this line to your model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_nested_set

  # ...
end
```

You can use a query like this to get all articles:

```
category = Category.find(1) # Or any category id

category.self_and_descendants.articles
```

Comment: Hi Tanzeeb, thanks for your comment. I installed the gem and ran the rebuild to get it all properly set up, but now I'm not sure how to set up an ActiveRecord relation with that for the use case I'm after.

Comment: Ah, category.self_and_descendants.articles is what I was looking for. I didn't know I could just add the articles object to an array and it would work. Thanks!